# config a router to act as a client and access another wireless router/network, wag120n

Tags: access-point, wireless-bridge, wifi

I currently have a WAG120N( http://www.linksysbycisco.com/EU/en/support/WAG120N) router and I would like to know if it's possible to configure it to connect to a different wireless network(WEP with no password) so I can get internet access on it and then to connect a pc to this router(WAG120N) so I can take advantage of the internet connection.

Basically I think that my need is a kind of yagi antenna but as I already got this router I would like to know if I can use instead it of yagi .
Thank you in advance for any answer !

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is use your wireless router in place of a wireless INTERFACE. This is called "bridging". Take a good look in your router settings for something called "Bridge Mode" or "Client Mode". This should be in the "Wireless" section of the settings. The manual could be helpful. Normally I would suggest flashing your router with the DD-WRT firmware but I checked on their website and it is not supported.

You will be able to do what you want. The thing that bothers me is that you will be using a fine piece of consumer grade hardware for something that a [cheap wireless interface](http://www.tp-link.com/gr/products/details/?categoryid=215&model=TL-WN722N) would suffice. If you decide to buy, just go with something with an external antenna.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course - that's what routers do (but its not acting as a "client" its just a router). But running a wifi network with no authentication is just asking for trouble.

Its not clear what the problem you are trying solve is. Is the PC out of range of the current router? If so, just use a Wifi repeater. You've flagged this as 'wireless bridge' does that mean you have no wifi on the PC? Adding a Wifi adapter would be a lot cheaper than buying another router.

C.

Comment: Basically the wifi is too far from my PC so I cannot directly access the wifi spot therefore I was looking to use the router(as it has better range) to connect to the wifi and then simply connect the pc to the router via ethernet or wireless .

Comment: If you already have the hardware in lpace - then yes - use the Wifi router as a router.